# Problems with epagex and offset

Tags: jquery, css

Hello stackoverflow community, I need help. I'am trying to do this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.slider-left-image').on( "mousemove", function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    jQuery('.slider-left-image').css("width", e.pageX - offset.left);
    jQuery('#koordinatesX').val(e.pageX - offset.left);
    jQuery('#koordinatesY').val(e.pageY - offset.top);
  });
});
```

But when i resize it aint plusing back to right. Can you help me? When i use this:

```
jQuery('#koordinatesX').val(e.pageX - offset.left);
```

It returns back from 0 width to set 640. But with this:

```
jQuery('.slider-left-image').css("width", e.pageX - offset.left);
```

It goes to zero but not back to 640 or etc here is jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tg7h1ewL/

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet doesn't work. I've modified it a little bit and it displays something... not sure what you mean though. Could be that you are trying to resize the image and its width goes down to 0 but you are not able to go other way around.

Here is the code snippet for you: https://jsfiddle.net/tg7h1ewL/1/

Basically try playing around with a bigger offset and instead of this

```
jQuery('.slider-left-image').css("width", e.pageX - offset.left);
```

do the following:

```
jQuery('.slider-left-image').css("width", e.pageX - offset.left + 5 );
```

What it does is it extends the area where mouse cursor movement is being recorded meaning it can actually record and act on right movement where the previous code was only handling movement to the left.